# Treebanks that contain both constituency and dependency parse trees

Tags: syntax-trees, parsing, online-resources, annotated-data, treebanks

I am looking for treebanks that contain both constituency and dependency parse trees. Both should have been manually annotated (i.e. the dependency parse trees shouldn't have been obtained from the constituency parse trees).

Comment: @jknappen I care, sorry I simply forgot to vote :)

Answer (score 1):

For Hungarian:

[Szeged Treebank](http://rgai.inf.u-szeged.hu/SzegedTreebank) contains manually annotated constituency parse trees; [Szeged (Dependency) Treebank](http://rgai.inf.u-szeged.hu/dependency) contains dependency parse trees that were automatically derived from the constituency parse trees, then corrected by human annotators:

> The Szeged Dependency Treebank is a dependency-tree format version of the Szeged Treebank. From the originally phrase-structured treebank, we produced dependency trees by automatic conversion, checked and corrected them thereby creating the first manually annotated dependency corpus for Hungarian.
>
> The corpus contains 82,000 sentences, 1.2 million words and 250,000 punctuation marks. Texts were selected from six different domains, ~200,000 words in size from each.

References:

- Szeged Treebank 1.0:
  Csendes, Dóra; Csirik, János; Gyimóthy, Tibor 2004: [The Szeged Corpus: A POS Tagged and Syntactically Annotated Hungarian Natural Language Corpus](https://web.archive.org/web/20140324043010/http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu:80/coling2004/W8/pdf/03.pdf). In: Proceedings of the 5th International Workshop on Linguistically Interpreted Corpora (LINC 2004) at The 20th International Conference on Computational Linguistics (COLING 2004), Geneva, Switzerland, 23-29 August, pp. 19-23.
- Szeged Treebank 2.0:
  Csendes, Dóra; Csirik, János; Gyimóthy, Tibor; Kocsor, András 2005: [The Szeged Treebank](https://doi.org/10.1007/11551874_16). In: Matoušek, Václav et al. (eds.): Proceedings of the 8th International Conference on Text, Speech and Dialogue (TSD 2005), Karlovy Vary, Czech Republic, September 12-16, 2005, Springer LNAI 3658, pp. 123-131.
- Szeged Dependency Treebank:
  Vincze, Veronika; Szauter, Dóra; Almási, Attila; Móra, György; Alexin, Zoltán; Csirik, János 2010: [Hungarian Dependency Treebank](http://www.lrec-conf.org/proceedings/lrec2010/pdf/465_Paper.pdf). In: Proceedings of the Seventh Conference on International Language Resources and Evaluation (LREC'10), Valletta, Malta.

Comment: I hope none of this was done using that UD (Universal Dependencies) annotation scheme. That scheme is linguistically quite implausible.

Answer (score 1):

**Italian**

There is the [Italian Syntactic Semantic Treebank](http://catalog.elra.info/product_info.php?products_id=887) available from ELRA.

Answer (score 1):

**Spoken Japanese**

TueBa-J/S (created within the Verbmobil project) available from [Tübingen University](http://www.sfs.uni-tuebingen.de/en/ascl/ressourcen/corpora/tueba-js.html)

Answer (score 1):

**Basque**

[GrAF version of the Basque Dependency Treebank](http://repositori.upf.edu/handle/10230/17098)

Answer (score 1):

**Meta-answer: How did I find those doubly annotated treebanks?**

I visitied the [CLARIN Virtual Language Observatory](https://vlo.clarin.eu) and entered the following words in the search slit:

```
treebank dependency constituency
treebank dependency constituent
```

This provides me with a short list of treebanks.